# Virtual deployment directory in jboss in domain mode

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy multiple .war files present in external deployment directory.

I tried it using standalone mode with below configuration in standalone.xml,

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
<deployment-scanner path="javaproject" relative-to="my.deployment.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
</subsystem>
```

And path element,

```
<paths>
<path name="my.deployment.dir" path="C:\projectdeployment\standalone\Server\project"/>
</paths>
```

With above configuration, I can successfully deploy war files present under javaproject directory in standalone mode (without using cli and webconsole of jboss).

So Here is my question,

If I want to use similar method using domain mode then what changes I have to make in domain.xml?

If it is possible then I just need to copy and paste newly build war file in my external deployment directory and jboss will pick-up the changes and then restart only needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported in domain mode. You need to deploy via the management API, CLI or administration console.